# Segmentation Fault. Why?

Tags: c

I am attempting to access a file and fscanf the data into a 2d array, but whenever I run the code I get Segmentation fault (core dumped). I have tried looking for an explanation as to why, but can't seem to find one. I know the file I am attempting to open is in the correct location and is not spelled wrong. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define FILENAME "rocket1.txt"


int main(void)
{
FILE *rocket1;
int i, NROWS, NCOLS, k, num_data_pts;
double x[NROWS][NCOLS];

rocket1 = fopen(FILENAME,"r");
        if(rocket1 == NULL)
         {printf("Error opening file.\n");}

fscanf(rocket1,"%d",&num_data_pts);

for(i=1;i<=num_data_pts;i++)
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
        fscanf(rocket1,"%lf",&x[i][k]);



    fclose(rocket1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a start, you're not defining NROWS or NCOLS - so you don't know the dimensions of your array.  You'll need to learn how to use GDB, so that you can debug problems on your own.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your Program try like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define FILENAME "rocket1.txt"
#define NROWS 10
#define NCOLS 10
int main(void)
{
    FILE *rocket1 = NULL;
    int i, k, num_data_pts;
    double x[NROWS][NCOLS];
    rocket1 = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (rocket1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fscanf(rocket1, "%d", &num_data_pts);
        if ( NROWS <= num_data_pts || NCOLS < 4 )
        {
            printf("Post Fence Error. Increase Array Size.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 1; i <= num_data_pts; i++)
                for (k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                    fscanf(rocket1, "%lf", &x[i][k]);
            fclose(rocket1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here for demonstration purpose NROWS and NCOLS are taken as 10.
In your code you accessed x[i][k] from index 1(not 0) for i and
extended upto num_data_pts(inclusive). So, extra checking is included
to prevent access outside the array size.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main problems here:

1. You are declaring NROWS and NCOLS but not initializing them.

   ```
   int NROWS, NCOLS;
   ```

simply allocates memory for 2 integers. What about their initial values? You need to assign suitable values else they might contain garbage data.
Something like:

```
    int NROWS = 10, NCOLS = 10;
```

is desirable.

2. You're trying to open a file "rocket1.txt". There's a problem with this code:

   ```
   rocket1 = fopen(FILENAME,"r");
   if(rocket1 == NULL)
    {printf("Error opening file.\n");}
   ```

if rocket1 is NULL, then you do print an error but then you should typically terminate the program.

```
    rocket1 = fopen(FILENAME,"r");
    if(rocket1 == NULL) {
       printf("Error opening file.\n");
       exit(1);
    }
```

Exiting the program is important since if rocket1 = NULL, then any subsequent reference to rocket1 might result in a NULL pointer deference which is going to segfault.

Hope this helps!